# Remove parent nodes if contains tag

Tags: domdocument

I'm trying to remove url elements from my sitemap if they contain a priority tag. What am I doing wrong?

Script:

```
<?php

$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xml->load('sitemap.xml');

$priorities = $xml->getElementsByTagName('priority');
foreach($priorities as $priority){
    $xml->removeChild($priority);
    }

echo $xml->saveXML();
```

Existing sitemap:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url><loc>https://www.example.tld/</loc></url>
<url><loc>https://www.example.tld/file</loc></url>
<url><loc>https://www.example.tld/folder/</loc><priority>0.7</priority></url>
<url><loc>https://www.example.tld/folder2/</loc><priority>0.3</priority></url>
</urlset>
```

Desired sitemap:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url><loc>https://www.example.tld/</loc></url>
<url><loc>https://www.example.tld/file</loc></url>
</urlset>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `parentNode` of `$priority` instead of `$xml` to remove the child.

Instead of using a foreach, you  can loop the collection using a for loop decrementing the value of `$i`

```
$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xml->load('sitemap.xml');

$priorities = $xml->getElementsByTagName('priority');
for ($i = $priorities->length - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    $priorities[$i]->parentNode->removeChild($priorities[$i]);
}
echo $xml->saveXML();
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked at removing the priority tags. I tried to modify it by adding another layer of parentNode-> to try to take the url tag out, but that failed to run. $priorities[$i]->parentNode->parentNode->removeChild($priorities[$i]);

Comment: @GFL If you want to do it like that, in remove child you would have to use the parent node of `$priorities[$i]` llike this `$priorities[$i]->parentNode->parentNode->removeChild($priorities[$i]->parentNode);`